# Get parent directory of a specific file

Tags: python

There is a file `a.py`.

The location is `/home/user/projects/project1/xxx/a.py`.

If  I call `os.getcwd()`, it gives me `/home/user/projects/project1/xxx/`. But I want to reach `/home/user/projects/project1`. How can i do this in Python?

**Edit :** I think i must be more clear. i want this for my Django project.

i use these codes in my settings.py:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

then i use fallowing code to specify where my static file folder is. :

```
os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'statics'),
```

my settings.py file is under: `/home/user/projects/project1/xxx/settings.py`

my static file folder is under same dir as `settings.py`.

now i want to move this folder to `/home/user/projects/project1`

what should i do with code that in settings.py

thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/tmp/test'
>>> os.chdir('..')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/tmp'
>>>
```

The dot dot (`..`) represents the parent directory. Because relative path names specify a path starting in the current directory.

See the documentation of [`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.chdir#os.chdir).

Comment: Consider using `os.pardir` instead of `'..``.  On *most* systems, they'll be the same thing, but I suppose there might be one or two obscure systems out there where they are different.

Answer (score 13):

```
from os.path import dirname

print(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
```

Each time you call `dirname` it gives you parent directory. Call as many times as necessary.

Alternatively you can do following:

```
normpath(join(path1, '..', '..'))
```

Comment: Rather than hardcoding `'..'`, consider using `os.pardir` instead.